# the condition in if statement is always true

Tags: java, android

i am new to this language and as i was working i was not able to figure out why the condition is always false and the if statement does not seem to work. i am trying to generate random images in android studio but without repetition.

```
  private int getRandomImage() 
  {
    int count = 0;
    int select;
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (count < mImageIds.length) {
        select = r.nextInt(mImageIds.length);
        if (!numbers.contains(select)) {
            numbers.add(select);
            count++;
            return mImageIds[select];
        }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe because `numbers` is empty ? ;)

Comment: `return mImageIds[select];` will break the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should solve your problem.

You'll first want to define some fields outside of the scope of your method

```
  Random r = new Random();
  List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  int count = 0;

  private int getRandomImage() {
      int select;
      if (count < mImageIds.length) {
          select = r.nextInt(mImageIds.length);
          while(numbers.contains(select)) {
              select = r.nextInt(mImageIds.length);
          }
          numbers.add(select);
          count++;
          return mImageIds[select];
      }
      return -1;
  }
```

Now when you add Integers to `numbers` they will not be wiped as you were reinstantiating numbers every time you called the method. Also the count of how many pictures you have used will not be reset in a similar manor.

You will want to use a while loop to make sure that you have a unique value.

I have also changed the escape value of the method from 0 to -1 so you won't accidentally return the first indexed picture in the case where you have already used every picture.

Answer (score 4):

I annotated the key parts in the code with `^^^^` markers to demonstrate the flow of things:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -> numbers is empty

while (count < mImageIds.length) {
    select = r.nextInt(mImageIds.length);
    if (!numbers.contains(select)) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ numbers is empty -> does not contain select -> true

        numbers.add(select);
        count++;
        return mImageIds[select];
        ^^^^^^ -> leaving the function, the if-statement above will not be reached again

    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation